# Steady State Calculation in Markov Chain in R

Tags: r, markov-process

I am using the package markovchain in R.
My transition matrix looks like this

```
> transition_matrix
     Arriving Playing.on.Phone Paying.Attention Writing.Notes Listening Kicked.Out
[1,]        0              0.5             0.50           0.0         0       0.00
[2,]        0              0.0             0.99           0.0         0       0.01
[3,]        0              0.8             0.00           0.2         0       0.00
[4,]        0              0.0             0.00           0.0         1       0.00
[5,]        0              0.0             0.00           1.0         0       0.00
[6,]        0              0.0             0.00           0.0         0       1.00
```

Now I am building a markov chain object

mcstates <- new("markovchain", states = colnames(transition_matrix),
                 transitionMatrix = transition_matrix ,name = "state")

Setting initial value as

```
init <- c(1,0,0,0,0,0)
```

After 10 steps

```
> init * (mcstates ^ 10)
     Arriving Playing.on.Phone Paying.Attention Writing.Notes Listening Kicked.Out
[1,]        0        0.1573841        0.1947628     0.3309517 0.2886897 0.02821181
```

After 100 steps

```
> init * (mcstates ^ 100)
     Arriving Playing.on.Phone Paying.Attention Writing.Notes Listening Kicked.Out
[1,]        0     4.361078e-06     5.396834e-06     0.4807651 0.4759563 0.04326881
```

After 1000 steps

```
> init * (mcstates ^ 1000)
     Arriving Playing.on.Phone Paying.Attention Writing.Notes Listening Kicked.Out
[1,]        0     1.163927e-51     1.440359e-51     0.4807692 0.4759615 0.04326923
```

Showing that there is no change in distribution

However when I try to calculate the steadystate

```
> steadyStates(mcstates)
     Arriving Playing.on.Phone Paying.Attention Writing.Notes Listening  Kicked.Out
[1,]        0     8.211848e-16     1.055809e-15     0.5170262 0.5170262 -0.03405231
[2,]        0     0.000000e+00     0.000000e+00     0.0000000 0.0000000  1.00000000
```

I have two questions

1. How is the steady state different from the stationary distribution I am hitting when I keep on multiplying with the transition matrix
2. Why is there a negative probability in the steady state solution

Any insight on this will be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don’t know this package, however I note that your Markov chain has one absorbing state, Kicked.Out, and a stable orbit of two states, Writing.Notes and Listening. I would expect two stationary distributions, `0  0  0  0.5 0.5  0` and `0 0 0 0 0 1`. Of course any combination of the two is stationary, eg `0   0   0 0.48 0.48 0.04`.

Comment: (cont) The solutions found by `steadyStates` are not ok because of the `-0.034` showing at the end of the first one, but note that `(1 - 0.034) * x[1,] + 0.034 *x[2,]` would allow to find ` 0  0  0  0.5 0.5  0` which is correct.

Answer (score 2):

I write this post as author of markovchain package. On August 2016 I pulled a fix to the package that should close the issue. Basically, the above transition matrix (TM) was composed by more than one closed class. Numerical issues could arise when solving the eigenvalue problem. So, we have decided to find the steady state distribution by closed class and to merge togheter. HTH

Answer (score 1):

I believe steadystate is finding the eigenvectors of your transition matrix which correspond to an eigenvalue of 1.  The vectors supplied are thus a basis of your steady state and any vector representable as a linear combination of them is a possible steady state. Thus your steady states are:
(0,0,0,a,a,b)/(2*a+b) and (0,0,0,0,0,1)

This is consistent with the subsequent observations by @Elvis.